# Most efficient multiple condition IF statement

Tags: performance, visual-basic

I am using a function to compare over 100 variables inside of classes to each other an am curious if one method of comparing multiple condition statements is more efficient than another.  I am currently considering one of these methods.  I think the 'single If using And/Or' looks the cleanest but performance is more important. (my code is VB.Net)

Multiple ElseIf

```
If Not ClassA.num = ClassB.num Then
    Return False
ElseIf Not ClassA.str = ClassB.str Then
    Return False
Else : Return True
End If
```

Single If using And/Or

```
If Not ClassA.num = ClassB.num Or
   Not ClassA.str = ClassB.str Then
       Return False
Else : Return True
End If
```

Nested If

```
If ClassA.num = ClassB.num Then
    If ClassA.str = ClassB.str Then
        Return True
    End If
End If
Return False
```

Edit: Changed second code snippet from And to Or

Edit 2: Changed third snippet from If Not to If

Comment: You will want to read [Description of "short-circuit" evaluation in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817250)

Comment: the three examples are not equivalent; the first one returns false when ClassA.num != ClassB.num **OR** ClassA.str != ClassB.str

Comment: Rule 1) of Optimization - You Can not tell without profiling.
My experience of optimizers is that usually they do a much better job than me at this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Wayne: now the third snippet doesn't match the other two ;)

Comment: @Steven: Okay... this time they should all match  (if anyone was wondering: the first snippet was how I wrote my original code,  but I changed it to the second snippet using OrElse statements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it gets any more efficient than short-circuit evaluation for real trivial chains like this:

```
Return ClassA.intVariable = ClassB.intVariable AndAlso ClassA.longVariable = _
        ClassB.longVariable AndAlso ClassA.str = ClassB.str
```

Notice how `AndAlso` is used, not `And`.  Also shorter, quicker-to-compare stuff is mentioned (and evaluated) first, with longer, slower-to-compare stuff further in the back.

Comment: Most of my schooling was in C# so I did not know that in VB.Net using And / Or was not short-circuiting.